# В чем преимущество?

Tags: c++

Между вызовом

```
const QVector<T> oblabla(const T& t)
{
      //obladi blada
}
```

и

```
const QVector<T>& oblabla()
{
}
```

Интересует возвращаемый параметр.
Мол, во втором случае, не происходит копирование всего объекта в стек?

Comment: - В случае первого объявления функции `const` бессмысленен.
- Даже если бы в `Qt` не было `copy-on-write`, первый вызов в большинстве случаев не приводил бы к лишнему копированию из-за `RVO` (`return value optimization`).

Comment: Почему,он не продлит время жизни объекта?

Comment: @pol500 Модификатор `const` сам по себе никак не влияет на время жизни объекта, поскольку оно определяется в функциях, которые вызывают `oblalbla` и, соответственно, получают с ее помощью копию объекта типа `QVector<T>`.

Comment: Где об этом можно более подробно почитать?

Comment: `C++ Primer`, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `QVector::QVector ( const QVector<T> &other )`
>
> **⇨⇨⇨⇨⇨** Constructs a copy of *other*. **⇦⇦⇦⇦⇦⇦**
>
> This operation takes constant time, because QVector is implicitly shared. This makes returning a QVector from a function very fast. If a shared instance is modified, it will be copied (copy-on-write), and that takes linear time.

Не гадайте, читайте [документацию](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#QVector-4) же!

Comment: А кто минус поставил?

Comment: Наверно, один из многочисленных "врагов" @karmadro4'a на этом форуме :)

Comment: Да ну, многочисленных... юный мститель 1 шт. :-) А плюсы не ставят потому, что тема сисек и буквального "*преимущества*" из текста вопроса не раскрыта и не может быть раскрыта, т.к. у конструкторов разные контракты.

Comment: Стрелочки, кстати, няшные :)